# Do programs on Inactive Virtual Desktop still use the memory in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop, memory-usage

Really, I was wondering if there is a point to multiple desktops, beyond a users personal organization, Like is there some type of performance boost or something?

Specifically, If I have Chrome with 10 tabs open, or in my case Visual Studio 20XX, separably in 3 of the virtual desktops how dose this affect the system memory (RAM), are the windows in the inactive virtual desktops effectively minimized or is more like they are hibernated or suspended (in short taken out of memory)?

Example:

- Virtual Desktop 1 (Main project I am working on)

  - Chrome with 10 tabs
  - Visual Studio 20XX
  - various small utilities running
- Virtual Desktop 2 (project i am waiting on a response from the client)

  - Chrome with 10 tabs (related to project)
  - Visual Studio 20XX
- Virtual Desktop 3 (internal company stuff)

  - Chrome with 3 tabs (related to project)
  - company time keeping program

Will the system act as though i have 23 tabs, 2 instances of Visual Studio 20XX and other smaller programs (and in a general sense be sluggish because i have to much open) or will it act as though the only things open are the one on the active Virtual Desktop (if Virtual Desktop 1 is active are the instances of programs in Virtual Desktops 2 and 3 still running as well)?

Personally I do not see a point to the Virtual Desktop if it is not saving me memory or allowing my machine to run better. Overall it just seems like a more complicated way of grouping things on the task bar.

Comment: Should be easy enough to test.  I can tell you how you think virtual desktops work on Windows 10 is incorrect though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no memory benefit to using virtual desktops, it's purely organizational.

Microsoft is simply implementing a feature that other operating systems have offered for decades. I suspect that some people will use it heavily but most will ignore it.

The one place I've found virtual desktops to be useful was in my Solaris development days almost 20 years ago when we were running Smalltalk.

Most Smalltalk development systems used several windows concurrently making task switching to non-development tasks annoying as you would be constantly replacing all your development windows afterwards.

If you spent most of your time in only a few windows then the feature is not going to benefit you much but if if you do lots of multi-tasking spread out over dozens of related windows it's a useful tool.